# Python HTTPS Login to account to scrape data, is this bad practice?

Tags: python

I want to create a website that you can register on, and enter your Power/Gas company login info.

I will then have a Python scraper that gets your power/gas usage and creates bar charts and other information about it. The Python script will run monthly to update with the latest info.

Is this a terrible idea? I believe the passwords to the power company login will have to be saved in plaintext, there wouldnt be any other way to use them again later if they were encrypted.

I'm not sure if anyone will trust to give their logins to my website either.

Is this a bad thing to do, and should it just not be done, or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: You're immediately off to a bad start. Storing passwords in plaintext is never okay.

Comment: Well yes I know that, but it is the only way for this application correct?

Comment: The only acceptable way would be storing API access keys. If the power/gas companies do not offer those, your service might be illegal.

Comment: Ok, it is too bad that they do not have API access keys. I am worried that this website will be looked at as either illegal or "sketchy" so the more feedback I get here is just confirming my worries about this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whatever the context, having the password stored in plain-text is not good at all, even though I like your idea.
I don't think there could be another way to achieve this, except by having an agreement with the power company.

Comment: Thank you, we have come to the same conclusion on this. Just need some affirmation on here and thats what I got.